# How to make react-select disallow space in options?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component

We're looking into replacing an old tagging system with react-select 3.1. For historical reasons, we don't allow spaces in our tags (and changing that is complicated).

However! react-select seems to think spaces are totally fine in tags. What I *think* I want to do is make space be a thing that essentially says "hey I am done with this tag" just as enter and tab currently do — that matches our existing behavior and I would like to keep it if at all possible.

Is there a way to configure react-select to use this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to manage the state of `react-select`, making it a controlled component, but this is how you can achieve this:

```
import Select from "react-select/creatable";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        inputValue={inputValue}
        onInputChange={(v) => setInputValue(v)}
        onChange={(v) => setValue(v)}
        onKeyDown={(e) => {
          if (e.key === " ") {
            e.preventDefault();
            const newValue = {
              label: inputValue,
              value: inputValue
            };
            setValue((v) => {
              return [...(v ?? []), newValue];
            });
            setInputValue("");
          }
        }}
        value={value}
        isMulti
        options={[
          {
            label: "aaa",
            value: "aaa"
          },
          {
            label: "bbb",
            value: "bbb"
          }
        ]}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit exciting-meadow-679rh]